# how to setup a C# winforms application to host SignalR Hubs?

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I have read through the SignalR docs and watched a few of the videos, however I can not get SignalR to host within a winforms application.

I have tried using source code off the SignalR wiki: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host

If you look at the "Full Sample - Hubs", what is the "server" variable? I do not understand how this works or how to convert it to C#. According to the wiki "The default SelfHost implementation is built on HttpListener and can be hosted in any kind of application (Console, Windows Service etc). "

I would like to host SignalR in C# and consume it in asp.net. Could anyone please shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make this to work for C# and ASP.NET I had to use "Cross Domain".

In the JavaScript I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs'></script>
```

and added:

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8081/signalr'
```

Answer (score 3):

The sample in the Wiki works fine.

Please install the `SignalR.Hosting.Self` package using NuGet (Package Manager Console)

> Install-Package SignalR.Hosting.Self

The `Server` lives in the `SignalR.Hosting.Self` namespace.

#### Sample

#### Console Application

```
using System;

namespace MyConsoleApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8081/";
            var server = new SignalR.Hosting.Self.Server(url);

            // Map the default hub url (/signalr)
            server.MapHubs();

            // Start the server
            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);

            // Keep going until somebody hits 'x'
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo ki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public class MyHub : SignalR.Hubs.Hub
        {
            public void Send(string message)
            {
                Clients.addMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Asp.NET / Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8081/signalr"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       // create signalr hub connection
       myHub= $.connection.myHub;

       // start hub connection and call the send method
       $.connection.hub.start(function () {
           myHub.Send('Hello');
       });
    });
</script>
```

**Please leave a comment if you have additional answers**