# How to self host SignalR hub in c# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

There are a lot of tutorials out there for setting up SignalR selfhost in a console application or a background service.

e.g.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do it from winforms? there is a similar question here

[how to setup a C# winforms application to host SignalR Hubs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549902/how-to-setup-a-c-sharp-winforms-application-to-host-signalr-hubs)

but they have answered with a console app... so here is the code that works in the console:

```
        string url = @"http://127.0.0.1:8585/";

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I know I might need to start a separate thread but how would it keep running the server? I have tried using the same on load.

Comment: I think the code for console app should work for WPF as well. Did you try? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i have tried it onload and initialize but the server starts and ends.. the url does not work

Comment: @inN0Cent, about "server starts and ends": `using` block means that there will be executed `Dispose` method on instance created by `WebApp.Start<Startup>(url)` statement. in console app `using` block is not finished until user press enter (`Console.ReadLine();`). in wpf `using` block finishes without delay. try `WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);` (and stop it when appropriate like app.exit)

Comment: @ASh I cant believe i overlooked that! thanks a million its working! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using` block means that there will be executed `Dispose` method on instance created by`WebApp.Start<Startup>(url)` statement.

in console app `using` block is not finished until user press enter (`Console.ReadLine();`).

in wpf `using` block finishes without delay. try `WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);` (and stop it when appropriate like application Exit)